# Django migrations gives error when run separately in different machines

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

We are a team of developers working on Django project. We are facing issues with django migrations. if one developer makes changes in model and runs makemigrations>migrate sequence it generates some sqls in migrations directory. Now when other developer pulls the code, and run the same sequence it's putting code in bad state. We've been clearing our migrations directory locally to get rid of the issue, and sometimes clear all the data. Not sure what we're doing incorrectly. Please suggest the right way of using django migrations.

Note - All of us use separate instances of DB in local machine.

Comment: You should show what errors you are getting.

Comment: What database and Django version you are using?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Errors keep changing - Right now I'm getting this one -
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" already exists
I can see there are suggestions for this with fake-initial, which doesn't seem to work for me. I believe we're doing some fundamental problem in the way we're using migrations - I want to know if we're using django migrations correctly or not.

Comment: @Aison, I'm using postgres v 9.5.4 and Django v 1.10

Comment: Well, you've been getting yourself into problems by "clearing our migrations directory locally". Don't do that. The trouble is, now you've done it, you're completely out of sync.

Comment: ok, so let's say I make some change in the model, run makemigrations>migrate and push the code change. Now after this what other developer is supposed to do to have model changes in their own local database? For now, we're doing makemigrations>migrate in other dev's local machine.

Answer (score 0):

**makemigrations just create files**

> By running makemigrations, you’re telling Django that you’ve made some changes to your models (in this case, you’ve made new ones) and that you’d like the changes to be stored as a migration.
>
> Migrations are how Django stores changes to your models (and thus your database schema) - they’re just files on disk. You can read the migration for your new model if you like; it’s the file polls/migrations/0001_initial.py.

Under Version Control, after you push the migrations file, for example, 0001_initial.py. Other developers just pull the file then run

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate your_app 0001 # to see what happen

python manage.py migrate your_app 0001
```

More about the Version Control:

> Version control
>
> Because migrations are stored in version control, you’ll occasionally come across situations where you and another developer have both committed a migration to the same app at the same time, resulting in two migrations with the same number.
>
> Don’t worry - the numbers are just there for developers’ reference, Django just cares that each migration has a different name. Migrations specify which other migrations they depend on - including earlier migrations in the same app - in the file, so it’s possible to detect when there’s two new migrations for the same app that aren’t ordered.
>
> When this happens, Django will prompt you and give you some options. If it thinks it’s safe enough, it will offer to automatically linearize the two migrations for you. If not, you’ll have to go in and modify the migrations yourself - don’t worry, this isn’t difficult, and is explained more in Migration files below.